# "dns_probe_finished_bad_config" on Chrome ONLY, other browsers work normally

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns

Only Chrome browser has the mentioned issue and other browsers behave normally. I am able to visit websites on other browsers and also use ftp.

It seems the problem is not the machine dns resolver, as other applications are able to resolve dns. Any idea why only chrome browser (version 108.0.5359.124) is unable to resolve the dns on Ubuntu 22.04?

(NB: I connect/disconnect to VPNs regularly)

Update 1: Interestingly, the "sync tabs on other devices" get updated in this situation.

Update 2: It works well while I am connected to a VPN, but not working while it is disconnected from the vpn but connected o the internet.

Comment: I'd check to make sure you don't have an *misbehaving* extension added to your chrome.

Comment: Already disabled extentions in the both profiles I have in Crome.

Comment: The error changed to "dns_probe_finished_bad_secure_config" after disabling the extensions and relunched the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling "Use secure DNS" in chrome settings, along with disabling some extensions worked for me.

Comment: Which extensions did you disable? That info could really help future visitors :)

Comment: Desabled all the extensions had no different result for me and was not helpful. But playing with the "Use secure DNS" was the solution for me. Currently it is ON and set to "With your current service provider" which is not what I am happy with but at least I have working browser now.